# Включать header файлы в .cpp, а не .h

Tags: c++

Какое преимущество в билде от того, что `header` файлы будут включены в `.cpp`, а не `.h`? Как это влияет на время билда и какие в этом плюсы и минусы?

Раньше считал, что `header` должны по всем канонам включаться только в заголовочные файлы. (как вариант для того, чтобы `.cpp` файл оставался чистым, а все импорты можно было видеть в одном месте)

Пример:

`A.h`:

`inline void in_func(){}`

`B.h`

```
#include "A.h" ???
class B {
public: 
  void func();
};
```

`B.cpp`:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h" ??? 

void B::func()
{
  in_func();
}
```

Comment: а если в заголовочном файле не нужны эти файлы, зачем включать?

Comment: А можно пример? Я вот про это: Раньше считал, что header должны по всем канонам включаться только так же в заголовочные файлы.
А то не очень понятно о чем Вы говорите

Comment: а может быть я сам не правильно понел о чем вы говорите: что значит "  включаться только так же ?"

Comment: @ARHovsepyan исправил. Хотел сказать, что считал, что это "хорошая практика".

Comment: У вас вопрос так написан, будто "header файлы" и "заголовочные файлы" - это разные вещи. Вы хедерами называете только стандартные хедеры что ли?

Comment: Вопрос некорректно поставлен. Как будто нельзя включать .cpp-файлы или какие-нибудь .dat :) Или как будто их нельзя включать куда-то. Можно все - но не все имеет смысл. И еще повторюсь за всеми - что такое *header* в вашем понимании?

Comment: @Harry, согласен, у него сначала была  ошибка в выражении, и поправил не до конца. Но это может быть ошибкой невнимательности. И далеко не все умеют хорошо выразить свои мысли(у самого есть такой недостаток), думаю  лучше помочь  рассказав как нужно излогать

Comment: @Harry суть вопроса скорее в том.. если к примеру, я использую инлайн функцию в каком-то классе, который описан в `.cpp` файле. Имеет ли какое-то значение включу я заголовочный файл с этой функцией сам `.cpp` или в его интерфейс (в это случае, интерфейс класса будет в `header` файле).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat обновил еще раз. Возможно так будет более ясно, в чем суть вопроса.

Comment: Просто общее пожелание, не более того - делать зависимостей поменьше, чтоб при изменении одного файла требовалось перекомпилировать поменьше...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Простой пример:**

Допустим у вас, в заголовочном файле, есть прототип некой функции:

```
void foo(const std::string&);
```

И пусть в `cpp.` определяете так:

```
 void foo(const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream is(str);
    std::set<char> s;
    //...
}
```

тогда вам придется подключать и `<set>` и  `<sstream>`.  Если же в main.cpp вы эту функцию не используете, то внешняя компановка не нужна, и, соответственно    файлы `<set>` и `<sstream>` не подключаются и поиск имен производится в более узком пространстве.

Answer (score 5):

Разумеется будет преимущество в скорости сборки, если включать заголовочники в cpp. Так как если их включать только в другие заголовочники, то будет много лишних включений. Один заголовок включится в другой, этот другой включится еще в пять, эти пять еще в десять и так далее, пока не получится, что все заголовки включены во все заголовки. При этом скорость сборки снизится от того, что:

1. все заголовочники нужно физически прочитать с диска и включить в единицу трансляции и разобрать;
2. разбухшие единицы трансляции занимают больше памяти, конечно там не гигабайты, но все ж таки по чуть-чуть и набирается;
3. каждый заголовочник расширяет область поиска имен, это влияет на скорость этого поиска;

На самом же деле, включать заголовочники в cpp нужно не столько для ускорения сборки, сколько для разграничения видимости и структурирования. На практике, желательно, чтобы сущности имели как можно менее узкую область видимости, в идеале, только там где нужно. Так ими легче управлять. А область видимости в Си++ управляется, в первую очередь, с помощью заголовочников. В процессе разработки, если возникла потребность во включении какого-то заголовочника, спешить не надо, нужно посмотреть почему эта потребность возникла, может проект структурирован не совсем удачно.

Заголовочник следует рассматривать как интерфейс к содержимому cpp файла, в нем должно быть только то, что нужно для использования возможностей cpp.

Comment: Не соглашусь с тем, что "в общем никаких преимуществ нет" - это, не правда, так как если работаешь с хидер онли библиотеками порядочных размеров (например boost::geometry) или включать хидера целого  фреймворка (например Qt, у них есть заголовочник со всеми хидерами фреймворка чем ленивые быдлокодеры постоянно пользуются), то время компиляции возрастает значительно. На моей практике я как-то ускорил сборку проекта использующего Qt с 10-12 минут до минуты просто разнеся хидера

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch , поддерживаю обоими руками и ногами :) .h включать по возможности только в src, в хедерах же стараться использовать forward declaration , и будет счастье. Наверняка и из этих рекомендаций есть исключения, но чаще всего это будет лучше, чем включать в хедер... А ещё есть идеология pimpl , я не очень в ней шарю, но она вроде как позволяет вообще почти никогда в хедеры не включать ничего... (ну по факту там не будет ничего включено, компоновка будет легковесной, а реально включёнными окажутся лишь врапперы)